# Monitor stuck in HDMI mode

Tags: display

I changed the display mode of an [iiyama XB2783HSU monitor](http://www.iiyama.com/gb_en/products/prolite-xb2783hsu/) to HDMI, but I don't have an HDMI input. Now I cannot access the menu again because I constantly get the message "Signal Cable Not Connected!"

How can I factory reset it (the manual doesn't mention it) and/or change the display mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently (and I discovered it by chance) holding the "Auto" button for a few instant is enough. Completely counter-intuitive and undocumented, but that's it.

I hope this helps people with the same issue, I had a fit of rage after realizing that such a simple issue was ending up taking so much of my time.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](http://www.iiyama.com/gb_en/products/prolite-xb2783hsu/12824.download) the factory reset is done via the "Recall" menu item in the OSD.  But you're saying the OSD won't come up since it's stuck in HDMI mode.

One thing to try (if oyu haven't already) is unplugging it form the wall an letting it sit for a couple/few minutes, then plug it back in and try again.

If the OSD still doesn't come up, I'd suspect you have a faulty monitor.  Contact Iiyama's support via web (http://www.iiyama.com/gb_en/support/#customer-service) or by phone:

> Call 01926 819189 between 9:00am - 5:30pm Monday to Friday